# Jest Enzyme Warning of ReactTestUtils location

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using Jest with Enzyme (the former for a while, just starting with the latter).

The relevant versions from my `package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "enzyme": "^2.8.2",
  "jest": "^19.0.2",
  "react-addons-test-utils": "^15.5.1",
  "react-dom": "^15.4.2",
  "react-test-context-provider": "^2.1.2",
  "react-test-renderer": "^15.4.2"
},
```

And a simplified version of the test I'm trying to run:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';
import Dashboard from '../../../javascript/components/ecosystems/Dashboard';

describe('<Dashboard />', () =>{
  it('renders', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Dashboard routeParams={{}} />,
      {
          context: {
              executeAction: () => {},
          }
      }
    );
    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

which is giving me no errors, but the warning:

> ```
> Ran all test suites matching "Dashboard.test.js".
> console.error node_modules/fbjs/lib/warning.js:36
>   Warning: ReactTestUtils has been moved to react-dom/test-utils. Update references to remove this warning.
> ```

But I am trying out Enzyme rather than React's TestUtils. How do remove this warning?

Comment: Enzyme in fact relies on React TestUtils for some things it seems. The first thing I would try is to make sure React, ReactDOM and react-addons-test-utils are all the same version.

Comment: @MattHolland Unfortunately that wasn't it.